# PHP: Why is readdir working for me at command line but not browser?

Tags: php, command-line, permissions, filesystems, opendir

I have 2 folders:
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/
and
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/duh/

Both folders have the EXACT same perms, group, owner, everything.

If I set $path to the first one, no problems, I echo a list of files with 'html' in the filename.

If I set $path to the second one, it dies on the opendir(). However, it works fine from the command line, just not the browser.

Any ideas?

Here's my very simple code:

```
<?php
        $path = "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/duh/";

        $img_folder = opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");

         while (false !== ($file = readdir($img_folder))){
             if (eregi("html", $file)){
                echo $file;
             }
         }
    ?>
```

Comment: take off @ and you'll at least see what error it's giving, in case you didn't know @ suppresses error reporting that's why you don't know what the cause is

Comment: Sorry, I should've taken that off. I was testing something and it made it here. I am not using that now, I will edit.

Comment: What error does it give then? (besides "unable to open $path")

Comment: [Mon Aug 30 13:02:50 2010] [error] [client] PHP Warning:  opendir() [<a href='function.opendir'>function.opendir</a>]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid is 0 is not allowed to access /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/duh/ owned by uid 10012 in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/t.php on line 4
[Mon Aug 30 13:02:50 2010] [error] [client] PHP Warning:  opendir(/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/duh/) [<a href='function.opendir'>function.opendir</a>]: failed to open dir: Inappropriate ioctl for device in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/t.php on line 4

Comment: I should note that according to my /etc/php.ini safe_mode = Off;

Comment: do not trust any config file. trust to `phpinfo()` only. there is also actual php.ini file location mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The server that I'm working on has local config files for each vhost. safe_mode was set to on for the local conf.

Thanks to those that led me down the path.

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions on the `duh` folder? Remember that the webserver will be running under a different user ID than your shell account. Make sure the dir's mode 0755 so it's readable by all users.

oops, just your comment with the error message. So, yes, permissions error. `duh` is owned by user id 10012, while your web server's running as root. safe mode will not allow this. 'chown' the directory to be owned by root...

Of course, why is the webserver running as root? That's horribly insecure.

Comment: Perms are 755 and I even set the folder's owner to the webserver's uid.

Comment: Webserver is running as apache. What led you to think it was running as root?

Answer (score 0):

Well now you know the answer: its SAFE_MODE, one of the ugliest PHP features.
There are some workarounds, but the best of them is *run from this host as fast as you can!*
or find a way to disable it.